# Type Conversion Error in Coos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am try to convert http://www.raywenderlich.com/29460/collisions-and-collectables-how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d-2-x-part-2 tutorial into cocos2dx and getting error
 in this line: 
    CCString *collision = properties->objectForKey("Collidable");

```
void HelloWorld::setPlayerPosition(CCPoint position)
{
CCPoint tileCoord = this->tileCoordForPosition(position);
int tileGid = _meta->tileGIDAt(tileCoord);
if(tileGid)
{
    CCDictionary *properties = _tileMap->propertiesForGID(tileGid);
    if(properties)
    {
        CCString *collision = properties->objectForKey("Collidable");
        if(collision && (collision->compare("True")))
            return;
    }
}
_player->setPosition(position);
```

}

Comment: "... but what might that error be?", he wondered headscratchingly. Would help to add the error message.

Comment: it give error............invalid conversion from 'const cocos2d::CCString*' to 'cocos2d::CCString*' [-fpermissive]

Answer (score 0):

The compiler complains about the loss of "const-ness" of the CCString. The objectForKey method returns a `const CCString*` but you're assigning it to a `CCString*` which means it's no longer `const`.

You have three options to fix this, starting with the easiest:

- Declare your CCString const (no downsides to this other than not being able to assign another CCString to the same object):

`const CCString *collision = properties->objectForKey("Collidable");`

- Explicitly cast const away (this may not be allowed depending on compiler settings):

`CCString *collision = (CCString*)properties->objectForKey("Collidable");`

- Remove the `permissive` flag from compiler settings to ignore this error. Not recommended because it allows you to violate const-ness.